# IE 11 Script1002 Filter syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, array-filter

Hi there I get a error message in ie11 but not in chrome the error is Script1002 Syntax error

My code is as follows

```
 vm.NoOftroopMemEditReq = (vm.EventAttendees.TicketAttendees.filter(a => a.Attendees.some(Attendee => Attendee.IsEditRequired === true))).length;
```

Comment: IE11 doesn't support ES2015 arrow functions (like this `Attendee => Attendee.IsEditRequired === true`) replace it with normal function or use transpiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in IE 11 this symbol => don't work, replace => with ===

```
 vm.NoOftroopMemEditReq = (vm.EventAttendees.TicketAttendees.filter(function (a) { return a.Attendees.some(Attendee === Attendee.IsEditRequired === true); })).length;
```