# AngularJS Application running issues in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I am using AngularJS.  Project runs perfectly in Chrome but when I tried to use IE11 - nothings shows up.
Console shows me the following Error:

[image: Error]

[image: ErrorDetails]

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: arrow notation doesn't work in IE11, instead of `(...)=>{...}` use `function(...){...}` (I believe BabelJS can compile that for you)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of IE 11 Script1002 Filter syntax error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927297/ie-11-script1002-filter-syntax-error/46927705

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE 11 Script1002 Filter syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927297/ie-11-script1002-filter-syntax-error)